# Write text on image randomly in any direction (e.g: horizontal, vertical, diagonal(+45, -45))

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I want to write text in any direction on image. I got the two axis i-e x-axis, y-axis, but what to do when to write text in diagonal direction (+45, -45) ? Location should be taken randomly.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
import os

#  some lines of the code 
for img_name, label in zip(images_name_list,names_list): 
    im = Image.open(src_img_path+img_name)
    arial = ImageFont.truetype(font=font_name, size=font_size)
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

    y_cordinate ,x_cordinate, z_cordinate = np.random.randint(im.height/2) 
    ,np.random.randint(im.width/2), np.random.randint(im.diagonal/2)

    location = (x_cordinate,y_cordinate, z_cordinate)

 text_color = (000, 000, 000)
 d.text(location,label, font=arial, fill=text_color)

 im.save(dist_img_path+img_name)
```

y_cordinate ,x_cordinate, z_cordinate = np.random.randint(im.height/2) ,np.random.randint(im.width/2), np.random.randint(im.diagonal/2)

AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'diagonal'

Comment: I would suggest you use Python Wand to do that. It is based upon ImageMagick, which has an drawing function for writing text which can be at any angle. ImageMagick also has a random function as part of the fx method. See http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.5/wand/drawing.html and http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.5/wand/image.html. **Alternately**, with your code, just save the text as an image with a transparent background and then composite the text image onto the background image at whatever rotation you want to apply first.

Comment: The expection is pretty clear. Object ```im``` has no ```diagonal``` attribute. What do you expect this ```diagonal``` to be? How is it related to width and height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the opencv implementation of the above idea. You can use this code as a starting point. The idea is basically add your text in an empty image, rotate it at a desired angle and finally add it to your original image.

Code:

```
img = cv2.imread('bird.jpeg')

def rotate(src, angle):
    rows,cols = src.shape[:2]
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2), angle, 1)
    dst = cv2.warpAffine(src, M, (cols,rows))
    return dst

x = np.zeros((img.shape), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.putText(x, 'Stackoverflow Sample Image', (50, 200), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (0,0,255), 2)
x = rotate(x, 45)
res = cv2.bitwise_or(img, x)
```

Output:

**Figure 1**: Text rotated by -45 degrees.

[image]

**Figure 2**: Text rotated by 45 degrees.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197129/discussion-on-answer-by-anubhav-singh-write-text-on-image-randomly-in-any-direct).